# Does modify different field value thread safe in boost multi_index

Tags: boost, thread-safety, multi-index

I have:

```
struct employee
{
  uint64_t id;
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b;

  employee() { }

  struct By_id {};
  struct By_a {};
  struct By_b {};

  struct Change_a : public std::unary_function< employee, void >
  {
    uint32_t p;
    Change_a(const uint32_t &_p) : p(_p) {}
    void operator()(employee & r) { r.a = p; }
  };  

  struct Change_b : public std::unary_function< employee, void >
  {
    uint32_t p;
    Change_a(const uint32_t &_p) : p(_p) {}
    void operator()(employee & r) { r.b = p; }
  };   
};

typedef multi_index_container<
  employee,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique< tag<employee::By_id>, member<employee, uint64_t, &employee::id> >,
    ordered_non_unique< tag<employee::By_a>, member<employee, uint32_t, &employee::a> >,
    ordered_non_unique< tag<employee::By_b>, member<employee, uint32_t, &employee::b> >,
    >
> employee_set;

employee_set es;

typedef employee_set::index<employee::By_id>::type List_id;
typedef employee_set::index<employee::By_a>::type List_a;
typedef employee_set::index<employee::By_b>::type List_b;

//...
thread 1
List_id::iterator it_id;
es.modify( it_id, employee::Change_a( 0 ) );
thread 2
List_id::iterator it_id;
es.modify( it_id, employee::Change_b( 0 ) );
//...
```

This standart example how to work with boost multi index container.
if find some node by id and store iterator in List_id::iterator it_id;

I want to change (modify) different fields of employee in different threads.

Does the concurent operations are thread safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.MultiIndex has the same very basic thread safety guarantees than other containers in the standard library:

- Concurrent read-only access is OK.
- Concurrent write access must be externally synchronized by the user (you).

So, calls to `modify` (or any other operation resulting in changes in the container) must be guarded with some mutex-like mechanism.